# При малом времени задержки, смешиваются пакеты InputStream

Tags: java, c#, сеть

Ребята. Привет. Столкнулся с такой проблемой, если посылать пакеты из движка на сервер с частотой больше 20 раз / сек, то они начинают сливаться, в частности к началу нового добавляется конец старого. К примеру посылается две считай одинаковые строки action:login и ещё такая же. Но сервер видит как `action:loginaction:login`. Вот такая ситуация с TCP. Можно ли как то решить эту проблему?

```
if (inputStream.available() > 0) {
    System.out.println("Have messege");
    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    length = inputStream.read(bytes);
    String result =new String(bytes, 0, length);
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Я думаю вы сами понимаете, что передавать данные 10 раз в секунду это не очень.

Comment: добавьте к вопросу [mcve]

Comment: tcp так устроен. Вам нужно самостоятельно определять границу между пакетами. В простейшем случае можно просто заканчивать пакет переводом строки и читать с помощью `BufferedReader.readLine()`.

Comment: Вы почему-то предполагаете что то, что послано одним вызовом `write`, будет прочитано одним вызовом `read`. Это не так и никогда так не было. TCP — потоковая штука. Границы между сообщениями — ваша обязанность, а не протокола TCP. Хотите, чтобы за вас протокол следил за границами сообщений, вам нужно что-то высокоуровневое, например, SOAP.